# binary needs /lib64 but only /lib

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I have to copy some binary execution files (tools) from Intel, AMD, and NVIDIA.

Most of them used `/lib64` but my yocto environment only have `/lib`,

I do this way which works in the most cases:

```
do_install () {
   patchelf --set-interpreter /lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ${S}/foo
....
}
```

but I still see some binaries didn't work this way, I still need to manually create /lib64, ex:

```
ln -s /lib /lib64
```

then the binary will run, otherwise, it terminated directly.

How to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is that if you set:

```
BASELIB = "lib64"
```

in your build, it will use /lib64  instead of /lib

Comment: since part of binaries already using /lib, this seems can't work in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

It probably works using following commands:

```
 IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND_append = " symlink_lib64;

symlink_lib64() {
    ln -s /lib ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/lib64
}
```

If you have your own image.bbclass you can change it there or manually change it in your used .bbclass file. For Example like it is done [here](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-selinux/tree/classes/selinux-image.bbclass?h=master)

You can also add it to your local.conf

Similar Problem is stated [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2018-November/043478.html)

Comment: where should I add these lines? in the recipe or local.conf ? any example, please.

Answer (score 0):

As Florian Berndi mentions, you can use the IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND to include a function that symbolically links the lib to lib64.

I have managed to successfully do this on Yocto Kirkstone in an image recipe I have setup in my layer.

Example:

```
# symbolic link lib64 directories to lib
IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND += "symlink_libs64;"

symlink_libs64() {
    ln -s /lib ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/lib64
}
```